# How to perform HTTP request using headers that involves redirect in Java

Tags: java, python, apache, go

I am in a weird situation where I am not sure what exactly the problem is. I need to do a simple HTTP to get a request in Java with an authorization header. I am using Apache HTTP client to do so but I am constantly getting `400`, here are a couple of my attempts.

Attempt 1:

```
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
    .setDefaultRequestConfig(RequestConfig.custom()
        .setCookieSpec(CookieSpecs.STANDARD).setRedirectsEnabled(true).build())
    .build();

HttpUriRequest request = RequestBuilder.get()
    .setUri("https://example.com/")
    .setHeader("Authorization", "<key>")
    .build();

HttpResponse resp = httpClient.execute(request);
System.out.println(resp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
```

Attempt 2:

```
//Using HttpURLConnection 
URL newUrl = new URL("https://example.com/");
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) newUrl.openConnection();
con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "<key>");
con.setDoInput(true);
con.setRequestMethod("GET");
con.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
System.out.println(con.getResponseCode());
```

and I tried numerous other approaches but all the attempts gave me a 400 response code. Note that the URL I am using involves a redirect.

Now when I try the same in Python I get `200`:

```
import requests
r=requests.get("https://example.com/", headers={"Authorization":"<key>"})
print(r.status_code)
```

Now when I do the same in Go I get `200`:

```
import (
    "net/http"
    "fmt"
)
req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", "https://example.com/", nil)
req.Header.Add("Authorization", "<key>")
resp, _ = api.Do(req)
fmt.Println(resp.StatusCode)
```

I am confused what could be the reason why it is not working in Java. The error message I get back from Java request is like this:

> `InvalidArgument`Only one auth mechanism
> allowed; only the X-Amz-Algorithm query parameter, Signature query
> string parameter or the Authorization header should be
> specified

Comment: Please have a look at this, You need to remove some headers before redirection happens. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17970633/header-values-overwritten-on-redirect-in-httpclient

Comment: @Jabir thanks, it was helpful, I didnt had to remove any header but just needed to add some

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally got it working, thanks to Jabir's comment, the link really did helped me solve the problem. Here is how I got it working

```
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
    .setDefaultRequestConfig(RequestConfig.custom()
        .setCookieSpec(CookieSpecs.STANDARD).setRedirectsEnabled(true).build())
    .setRedirectStrategy(new LaxRedirectStrategy() {

        public boolean isRedirected(HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response, HttpContext context)  {
            boolean isRedirect=false;
            try {
                isRedirect = super.isRedirected(request, response, context);
            }
            catch (ProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }  
            if (!isRedirect) {
               int responseCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                if (responseCode == 301 || responseCode == 302) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return isRedirect;
        }
        @Override
        public HttpUriRequest getRedirect(HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response, HttpContext context) throws ProtocolException {
        String cokeis = response.getHeaders("Set-Cookie")[0].getValue();
        HttpRequestBase requestBase = new HttpRequestBase() {
            @Override
            public String getMethod() {
                return "GET";
            }
        };
        requestBase.setURI(getLocationURI(request, response, context));
        requestBase.setHeader("Cookie", cokeis);
        return requestBase;
        }
    })
    .build();

HttpUriRequest request = RequestBuilder.get()
    .setUri("https://example.com/")
    .setHeader("Authorization", "<key>")
    .build();

HttpResponse resp = httpClient.execute(request);
System.out.println(resp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
```

I still cant believe though the complexity involve in apache java http client to do simple http get request that redirects compared to other languages.